# Android: transparent background automatically replaced by random image

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm experimenting a strange behavior of my application: all the transparent backgrounds are being replaced by a random image.
This is an example (sorry for the big size):

[image]

This is an activity with a RelativeLayout in the center (with transparent background) containing a listView (every cell has transparent background). 
You can see that there is this huge logout image replacing all transparent backgrounds. This image is used in a totally different layout and doesn't appear at all in the xml file of the layout of the activity.
This issue is present only (as far as i know) with the Samsung Galaxy Note (which i hate with all my body and heart) and it all works smooth and fine in every other device that i work with and in the emulator too.
I have already cleanedthe project, reinstalled the app and all the other trouble-shooting preliminary practices that i know.

Does anyone have any idea on the reason why this is happening?

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/io_guido_background" >

    <!-- header -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pezzo_bar"
        android:gravity="top" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_bar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titolo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:text="Archivio"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- body -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerlayout" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="480dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- box date -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sceltadate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/io_guido_rect_2" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/io_guido_periodo"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Da: "
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/dabtn"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/textedit_state"
                        android:onClick="setData" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:text="A: "
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/abtn"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/textedit_state"
                        android:onClick="setData" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!--  -->


            <!-- body lista -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="338dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/legenda"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sceltadate"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/subbody"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/backgroung"
                    android:background="#f3f3f3" >
                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backgroung"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/io_guido_rect_3_new" />

                <!-- logo

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_trasparente" />
                 fine logo -->


                <!-- lista -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutlista"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@id/android:list"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent" >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- sfondoTop -->
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- fine bodyLista -->


            <!-- body legenda -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/legenda"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <!-- Prenotata -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ready" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Prenotata"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- In corsa -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/pronta" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="In corsa"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- terminata -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ok" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Terminata"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Annullata -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/x" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Annullata"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- fine body legenda -->

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- fine body -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout xml for this activity?

Comment: Kindly post the xml and code

Comment: I've posted the xml... hope it helps solve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try create a special layout for this kind of device particularly?
Some time ago I had a similar problem and it was solved with creating a new layout with screen specifications of this device.

The reason why this is happening is that when you create a default layout it is created to be used with medium screen density. 
When you run the application on higher density screen, Android try to fill the layout to screen size and density. 
If Android understand that the background will not fit correctly with the screen density it will try to use some other way of fill the background. 
Is known as a good practice create layouts for each density you want to support. 
IE, normal (mdpi), high(hdpi) and low (ldpi).

At runtime, the system ensures the best possible display on the current screen with the following procedure for any given resource:

"...The system uses the appropriate alternative resource
Based on the size and density of the current screen, the system uses any size- and density-specific resource provided in your application. For example, if the device has a high-density screen and the application requests a drawable resource, the system looks for a drawable resource directory that best matches the device configuration. Depending on the other alternative resources available, a resource directory with the hdpi qualifier (such as drawable-hdpi/) might be the best match, so the system uses the drawable resource from this directory.
If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current screen size and density
The "default" resources are those that are not tagged with a configuration qualifier. For example, the resources in drawable/ are the default drawable resources. The system assumes that default resources are designed for the baseline screen size and density, which is a normal screen size and a medium density. As such, the system scales default density resources up for high-density screens and down for low-density screens, as appropriate.
However, when the system is looking for a density-specific resource and does not find it in the density-specific directory, it won't always use the default resources. The system may instead use one of the other density-specific resources in order to provide better results when scaling. For example, when looking for a low-density resource and it is not available, the system prefers to scale-down the high-density version of the resource, because the system can easily scale a high-density resource down to low-density by a factor of 0.5, with fewer artifacts, compared to scaling a medium-density resource by a factor of 0.75. ..." (developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

To understand deeply how Android select the resources you can check this Topic: [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Hope this help.

Comment: That could probably solve it, but i would really like to know why this is happening... or i will be forced to create a new layout everytime this problem shows up!

Comment: The problem is that when you create a default layout it is created to be used with medium screen density. When you run the application on higher density screen, Android try to fill the layout to screen size and density. If Android understand that the background will not fit correctly it try to use some other way of fill that. Is known as a good practice create layouts for each density you want to support. IE, normal (mdpi), high(hdpi) and low (ldpi). You can deep on this topic here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem is that i didn't use any resource for the background of the custom_row of the listView... just android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

Comment: On this case, I suggest create a new transparent color resource, and set the custom_row background with this color. On this way, you specify what should Android use.

Comment: Thank you very much Sandro. Thankfully this problem is not showing anymore (i don't know why, ijust played a little bit with the layouts... changing some position, enlarging some object, ecc...).
But i did find your answers very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem. Was able to fix it by replacing `android:background="@color/transparent"` with `android:background="@null"`. It can be something specific for Samsung tablets (saw it on Galaxy tab).